# Excel 2016 VBA help (F1) not working anymore?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I just "upgraded" to Excel 2016. I use VBA somewhat frequently for work, and since I'm no polished programmer I would constantly use the F1 help functionality to learn more about certain objects or functions. I just noticed that whenever I press F1 inside the VBA editor now, I get a generic Visual Studio 2012 help site, and no specific information in regards to the object I'm trying to get help for: No context-sensitive help topics!

i.e. If I press F1 while selecting the word "Sheets" I get a generic help site instead of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193217.aspx

but if I press F1 while selecting the word "For", then I get https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278847(v=office.15).aspx which is what I want

Any way to work around this, or any tips you may have to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Works for me as intended in Excel 2016 as of December 2018 (worked earlier too). I wonder if that was a problem that was actually fixed, or it actually depends on various factors and may [still happen to some](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53942822/11683).

Answer (score 1):

The VBA documentation is now on GitHub - you can fork/clone it, and submit pull requests to fix any errors you find!

https://github.com/OfficeDev/VBA-content/tree/master/VBA

It's pretty horrible to navigate the files, but there's a TOC for every topic:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/VBA-content/blob/master/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/TOC.md